# How can I rotate (twist) a particle field in 3D Studio Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I have a particle array emitting from an orb rising out of "goop" that I want to *twist* as they emit, to where it forms a tornado like effect around the object.

[image]

## How can the PArray be modified to do so?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is regarding 3D modeling.  Please commit to the [site proposal for 3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics)

Comment: I've committed. I've even tried to create a 3D exchange before. It's one of those odd things that people need, just not all of the time. 3D has had to wander as a nomad between Graphic Design and Gaming... Please be kind to 3D. You may have a 3D question someday with nowhere to turn!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a 3D Studio Max person at all but a quick google search found me:

[image]

[image]

There's much more to the tutorial located on [3dm3.com/tutorials/tornado/](http://www.3dm3.com/tutorials/tornado/) but since you already have something you're working with it seemed silly to give you instructions from scratch. I'm sure you'll have to look over the settings and apply them to your own objects/particles. Hope this helps you though.

A lot of the other tutorials I found use something called FumeFX plugin.